# Can I WaitForMultipleObjects on an event and an IOCompletionPort having input?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I am adding support for a FTDI driver to an existing code base which communicates with serial ports and pipes using Overlapped IO and an IOCompletionPort. I would like to interface directly with the FTD2xx.dll rather than use the virtual com port function (http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer%27s_Guide%28FT_000071%29.pdf).
The problem is that, as far as I understand, the FTD2xx.dll emulates Overlapped IO but is not compatible with an IOCompletionPort. It is however possible to pass in an event which is set whenever anything has changed in the drivers internal state. The program I'm updating has very low throughput but requires insanely low latency (real time communication with an embedded system).

So my question is how can I wait for either an event to be signaled or an IOCompletionPort to not be empty? Preferably not using any other threads.

Or alternatively could I use RegisterWaitForSingleObject with a call back which posts a custome message to the IOCompletionPort? I understand this uses the thread pool, could this increase latency in cases where the system is busy? (I can set my own thredas to high priority but I don't know anything about the priorities of the thread pool).

**Edit:** If I use the WT_EXECUTEINWAITTHREAD flag in RegisterWaitForSingleObject what thread is this "waiter thread" and what priority does it have?

Comment: I don't have any experience in this area so I won't make this an answer, but from the documentation WaitforSingleObjectEx should work if you set the bAlertable argument to true. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687036%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This will not work for me because I receive not only overlapped IO results from the waiting thread through the IOCompletionPort but also Custom messages and completion results from other threads and the docs state "The wait function returns and the completion routine is called only if bAlertable is TRUE, and the calling thread is the thread that initiated the read or write operation."

Comment: Well, for lowest latency, I would have gone with your least-preferred option - a high-priority dedicated thread that waits on the event.  If, however, the exiting code has the same latency constraints as your new requirement, and is currently in-spec, I would try first RegisterWaitForSingleObject and  PostQueuedCompletionStatus, as you suggest.

Comment: These choices just don't matter that much.  Of course WFSO has less latency, RWFSO makes you a good citizen on the operating system but grabbing the I/O completion thread doesn't come for free.  Minor details, what *really* matters is what happens when your program cannot respond for hundreds of milliseconds because your code got swapped out.  Or a video or audio driver runs a kernel thread with a priority that's always higher than yours.  If that cause failure due to a buffer overflow then you have a very unreliable system.

Comment: @Hans Passant thank you for reinforcing my gut feeling. The latency requirement is due to stupid embedded hardware needing an ACK or response within 2 milliseconds. If it does not get this responce in time the word does not end but I do get an error message and need to reinit a lot of stuff over a slow serial port which makes everything run much slower. So its ok if it happens now and then I just want it to happen as seldom as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IOCP is not a waitable object, so you cannot use it directly with any of the wait functions. What you can do is create a separate waitable event via `CreateEvent()` and then have a separate thread call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus/Ex()` and signal the event when an IOCP packet arrives.

Comment: this http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.networks.narkive.com/dIXQefU9/can-waitformultipleobjects-wait-on-an-iocompletionport-handle would suggest that it is a waitable event but the meaning is different from what I want.

Comment: That link does NOT suggest an IOCP is a waitable object, in fact it pretty much says the same thing I did - you have to use `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` to detect when an IOCP result is available. And if you read the actual MSDN documentation, an IOCP is not listed as one of the supported object types by the various wait functions.

Comment: you are right, I mis read. It doesn't look like what I wanted to do is possible and since your answer offers a valid work around I am accepting it. Thanks for correcting me above.